# Jupiter Notebook Dead Kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
```

This is my Python code which is throwing the following error on Jupyter Notebook

```
Kernel Restarting. The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

I was not getting this error until I `pip` installed polars. I am not sure the error, or how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this the only code you're running in the notebook?

Comment: And exactly how did you `pip` install polars?  The first line of your code is `import polars as pl` and so you would have gotten a modulenotfound error first anyway and so maybe the code problem wasn't coming up? If this seems a silly question because perhaps you are saying obviously you wouldn't have had the `import polars as pl` line there then consider it from out view, this is all we have to go on. Your post is terse and lacks details on what you did to troubleshoot. What if you run each of the lines you share separately? Which one triggers the issue? ...

Comment: <continued> Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay particular attention to the sections 'Searc, and research' and 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'. For the title aspect, consider writing the title for your future self a year from now when you forgotten about having this issue. What title would clue you in from a list of search results that this particular post is pertinent to the issue you are having right now.

Comment: That message isn't coming from your Python code per se, it's coming from the notebook. The kernel may be dying when trying to import Polars, but I agree with @Wayne: try running each line separately to find out.

Comment: FWIW, you might try remaking your environment using conda. (Polars is available in the coda-forge repo.) I *believe* conda and conda-forge packages are built more with compatibility in mind, so that might fix the issue if it's a compatibility problem at its heart.